# What do the different RAISERROR severity levels mean?

Tags: sql-server, raiserror

My best google result was [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/11/23/be-consistent-with-raiserror-severitites/):

- below 11 are warnings, not errors
- 11-16 are available for use
- above 16 are system errors
- there is no behavioral difference among 11-16

But, from BOL, "Severity levels from 0 through 18 can be specified by any user."

In my particular stored procedure, I want the error returned to a .Net client application, so it looks like any severity level between 11-18 would do the trick.  Does anyone have any authoritative information about what each of the levels mean, and how they should be used?

Comment: I don't know for other versions but I was very surprised to see that with SQL Server 2008, severity 16 do **NOT** terminate execution.

Comment: I use the same trick for a Delphi application, after trial and error i use level = 13. In this way the execution is not stopped (i raise the error in a trigger to display info the user) and the user gets the message. Of course it is a "terrible bad practice" but effective.

Comment: "Terrible bad practices" are necessary to get around many, many, many MS obstacles. Getting around MS obstacles, though, is usually a "good practice".

Comment: For anyone interested in a more in-depth exploration of sqlserver error handling see Erland Sommarskog's excellent series https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Answer (score 112, accepted):

[Database Engine Severity Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx)

You should return 16. Is the default, most used error level:

> Indicates general errors that can be
>   corrected by the user.

Don't return 17-18, those indicate more severe errors, like resource problems:

> Indicate software errors that cannot
>   be corrected by the user. Inform your
>   system administrator of the problem.

Also don't return 11-15 because those have a special meaning attached to each level (14 - security access, 15 - syntax error, 13 - deadlock etc).

Level 16 does not terminate execution.

When your intention is to log a warning but continue execution, use a severity level below 10 instead.

Comment: The MSDN link kind of says it all -- the information was right there in BOL, and I've never seen it before.  Thanks!

Comment: When you say "default", do you mean that an error level of 16 will be used if I call RAISERROR, passing no parameters.  i.e. it will be caught by a catch block?

Comment: Level 16 doesn't terminate execution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346/why-does-sql-server-keep-executing-after-raiserror-when-xact-abort-is-on. Unless I've missed something, you may want to update your answer.

Comment: A foreign key violation error also has severity 16. Other data integrity errors could also have this severity, I don't know, but if you're raising and handling "business rules" errors, 16 may be misleading. In my case, I ended up using out parameters for success (true or false) and error message.

Comment: @mcNux Is absolutely right, Level 16 does **not** terminate execution just tested on both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012. [Rolled back edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1122945/5).

Answer (score 11):

Severity Level `16` ***can*** Terminate Execution.

### TRY-CATCH Caveats with RAISERROR():

`RAISERROR()` with a Severity of **16** terminates execution for everything below the offending line.
***However*** this *only* applies when inside a Try-Block.

```
--DECLARE @DivideByZero Int = 1/0--Uncommenting this will Skip everything below.
RAISERROR (N'Before Try: Raise-Error 16.', 16, 0)--Works.
SELECT 'Before Try: Select.'[Marker]--Works.
BEGIN TRY
    RAISERROR (N'Inside Try: Raise-Error 16.', 16, 0)--Not displayed,but sends to Catch-Block.
    SELECT 'Inside Try: Select.'[Marker]--Skipped.
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR (N'Inside Catch: Raise-Error 16.', 16, 0)--Works.
    SELECT 'Inside Catch: Select.'[Marker]--Works.
    --RETURN --Adding Return will only skip what is After the Catch-Block for this scope only.
    --;THROW--Shows the RAISERROR() from the Try-Block and Halts Execution. Must include ";".
END CATCH
RAISERROR (N'After Try-Catch: Raise-Error 16.', 16, 0)--Works.
SELECT 'After Try-Catch: Select.'[Marker]--Works.
```

Surprised?  So was I.
What also threw me for a loop is not all Severity-**16**'s are the same.
If you were to uncomment the Divide-By-Zero line at the very top, then nothing below it would run.
The Divide-By-Zero logic will *also* generate a Severity-**16** Exception,
   **but** it is handled with a **full-stop**, unlike when thrown with `RAISERROR()`.

**Note:** Use `;THROW` as the ***last*** line inside your Catch-Block to properly
            throw the SQL Exception for the `RAISERROR()` event trigged by your Try-Block.
            This will effectively halt execution with a full-stop.
            The `;` Semicolon is required when other lines exist in the Catch-Block before calling `;THROW`.
If your logic properly handles the error in the Catch-Block (and you would like to continue processing
   the rest of the logic after it), then do *not* use `;THROW`.

### Conclusion:

Do not conflate a Severity-**16** thrown by the SQL-Server-Engine
   with one you raise yourself using `RAISERROR()`.
For all intents and purposes (when deliberately throwing your own errors), consider only 2 Severities:
     **0** (for Informational or Warning) and
   **16** (for Throwing an Exception handled within a Try-Block - to kick it out to the Catch-Block).

### Information Now!

**Note:** If you are using `RAISERROR()` to display Informational Messages,
            then I suggest using `WITH NOWAIT`:

```
RAISERROR('Read me right now!', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
RAISERROR('Read me whenever.' , 0, 1)
DECLARE @WaitSeconds Int = 10
DECLARE @WaitFor DateTime = DATEADD(SECOND, @WaitSeconds, 0)
WAITFOR DELAY @WaitFor
```

This is especially useful during long batch operations when you'd like some insight
   into how things are progressing as you reach certain milestone markers throughout the batch.
By *not* using `WITH NOWAIT`, you may never know when your Informational Messages might appear.
They could appear intermittently throughout the course of the batch, or all at once when the batch completes.

Comment: Does not terminate on Sql 2016 even with the `@divideByZero`