# Cannot get SQL error message

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am tring to run a sql script from my c# application

```
string sql = File.ReadAllText(sqlFile);
string[] QueryArray= sql.Split(new string[] { "GO" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string query in QueryArray)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Then my script contains raiserror statement

```
RAISERROR ('Cannot procees' , 20, 1) WITH LOG
```

When I try to access this error message form my C# application, that won't happen. The error message return to me is:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Where I have gone wrong. What Do I need to do to get the error returned by the `raiserror`

Comment: Your `RAISERROR` defines a severity of 20, which makes SQL Server terminate the current process...... use something between 11 and 19 instead! Then your process will stay in place, and you should be able to fetch the contents of your error from SQL Server

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP has not even properly opened a connection to the database.

Comment: @marc_s- But magically I was able to get the error randomly. But very rarely. Is that possible to happen. 
Without changing the  severity level, Is there any way to handle this from my c# application side? If I change the severity level, it works

Answer (score 1):

Try to change severity value -

```
RAISERROR ('Cannot procees', 16, 1) WITH LOG
```

Comment: Yes. that is works. But I am searching a way whether I can handle this from my C# application side without changing the sensitivity level

Comment: Just try to use `try\catch` block. And read this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122925/what-do-the-different-raiserror-severity-levels-mean

Comment: The code is already inside `try\catch`. I am getting that error message from `e.message`

Comment: `MSDN`: Severity levels from 20 through 25 are considered fatal. If a fatal severity level is encountered, the client connection is terminated after receiving the message. My two cents: for user errors use severity level 16.

Comment: The reason I am using level as 20 is I need to stop running the script at that point without proceeding. If I use 16 it will `raiserror` and continue the script.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have an article on this, [How to Retrieve Values in SQL Server Stored Procedures](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194792). This should give you an idea on how to resolve your problem.