# in T-SQL which error severity level, if any, lets the statement continue but causes SqlClient library to display a message

Tags: .net, t-sql, raiserror, system.data.sqlclient

I am not clear about T-SQL [error severity levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-ver15) **as they relate to the  `System.Data.SqlClient` library in .NET client applications**.  [bolded for emphasis in response to close-vote suggestion that I clarify how an answer about what severity levels "mean" does not address my question].

Which T-SQL error level(s) would allow the T-SQL statement to continue **but would cause the front-end to display the message**?

I thought it would be level 10 but that does not display a message in the front-end application; the docs say

> For compatibility reasons, the Database Engine converts severity 10 to severity 0 before returning the error information to the calling application.

Comment: Anything 10 or less. See http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#Severitylevels

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the different RAISERROR severity levels mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122925/what-do-the-different-raiserror-severity-levels-mean)

Comment: @Charlieface: In my tests, RAISERROR with level 10 does NOT do anything client-side. I may be missing something. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: "10: Here is an odd one: this level can never occur. Or more precisely, if a message with level 10 is raised, the level is for "compatibility reasons" converted to 0, and thus SSMS and other tools will only print the text."

Comment: @Charlieface: I mentioned that in my question.

Comment: I also don't understand the close vote. What is wrong with the question? My question is specifically about how the client-side .NET SqlClient library reacts to server-side severity levels. The other question suggested does not address this.

Comment: You're right, I got the wrong duplicate. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880471/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net for how to get info messages.